# Trying to print out 100 odd numbers

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class lab7 {
public static void isPrime(int n,boolean isPrime){
for (int div = 2; div < n; div++) {
        if (n % div == 0) { // n is not prime
           isPrime = false;
           div = n;
        }else{
     isPrime=true;
     }

     }   
     }

   // This program prints out the first 100 prime numbers

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int count = 0;
  int n = 1;
  boolean isPrime=true;

  // loop that iterates 100 times
  while (count <= 100) {

     // Use the isPrime method to check whether
     // the number n is prime or not
     if (isPrime(n)) {
        System.out.println(n + " is prime");
        count++;
     }

     // move on to the next n
     n++;
  }
 }
}
```

I'm trying to get the code to print out the first 100 odd numbers using a method called isPrime. I keep getting an error saying

```
    lab7.java:35: error: method isPrime in class lab7 cannot be applied to given types;
     if (isPrime(n)) {
         ^
required: int,boolean
found: int
```

How would I get rid of this and do what I want.

Comment: you are missing `}`

Answer (score 3):

Your `isPrime(int)` function should look like this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
 for (int div = 2; div < n; div++) {
  if (n % div == 0) { // n is not prime
   return false;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
 }

 return false;
}
```

Your implementation doesn't work because:

1. You're not returning `boolean` from the function
2. Java is *pass by value* therefore your variable `isPrime` is not updated

Also make sure not to mess up the difference between prime numbers and odd numbers.

Comment: You can delete the line `div = n` in from the middle of the function, though -- that line is dead code.

Comment: Didn't see that. Fixed.

Comment: it's enough to do `for (int div = 2; div < n / 2; div++)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see is that isPrime takes two variables, in your code on line 35 you only provided 1, the integer.

Comment: Also it has a `void` return type but should have a `boolean` return type.

Comment: Ahh, yes, my bad. I'm relatively new to Java!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class lab7 {
public static boolean isPrime(int n,boolean isPrime){
for (int div = 2; div < n; div++) {
        if (n % div == 0) { // n is not prime
           isPrime = false;
           div = n;
        }else{
     isPrime=true;
     }

     }
return isPrime;
     }

   // This program prints out the first 100 prime numbers

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int count = 0;
  int n = 1;
  boolean isPrime=true;

  // loop that iterates 100 times
  while (count <= 100) {

     // Use the isPrime method to check whether
     // the number n is prime or not
     if (isPrime(n, isPrime)) {
        System.out.println(n + " is prime");
        count++;
     }

     // move on to the next n
     n++;
  }
 }
}
```

I have corrected the code. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to check prime

```
public static boolean isPrime(int num){
        for(int i=2;i<num;i++){    
            if(num%i==0){
                return false;
            };
        };
        return num>1;
}
```